# Continous delivery with react-native

Tags: react-native, continuous-integration, appcenter

I am working in a company that developes its own internal android app using react native. We currently do not have too much devices but in the feature we will have many devices, and each time we want to update the app in devices, we need to connect the devices to computer and build via usb.

Is there a way to do some kind of continous delivery and deployment in all devices automatically by publishing somewhere the release and forcing all devices to download the new update?

I have tried app https://appcenter.ms/ and codepush but needs to be linked to play store. I do not want to upload our app to playstore, instead want to use a local server or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes. if you don't want to publish the application to plays tore and want t a force update . you need to develop a simple API what well return the version number .  also create a VERION_NUMBER in your APP Every time your update the application change version number in the api and in your application.  and on the first screen call your API and check if the version number is change the redirect user to application link where user can download the application .

you can keep your apk in your own server or somewhere else which one is easy for you

Comment: Thank you. Is there some way I can automate this? Download the apk in background and display the installation intent without making the user close the app, download, so on..

Comment: when user open the application it will show the alert to update. or you can send a notification and when user click on that your can download the application. but the with playstore automatic download is not possible